# Remote Desktop using VB from access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table inside that table 3 Columns {USERNAME,PASSWORD,IP}

I want to use that data to remote anyPC inside my network instead open the remote desktop and enter the user,pass and ip .

I used that code but that makes me open the remote desktop for an IP , but the user and password doesn't insert well.

That is my VB code

```
Private Sub Toggle133_Click()

Shell ("cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV" + ip.Value() + "/user:fourtex\" + Text126.Value() + "/pass:" + Text109.Value() & "mstsc.exe /v " + ip.Value())
Shell ("mstsc.exe /v " + ip.Value())



End Sub
```

Comment: Please bare in mind that VBA and VB.NET are not the same just because their first two letters are.

Comment: I deleted my answer because this issue appears to be with the commands themselves, and not VBA. You ought to get the commands working via CMD before implementing them in your code. If you are having problems you can always ask a question tagged with for instance `cmd` and `mstsc`.